# Pycharm autocomplete in Python with static files path

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I wrote a Django function like this:

```
def send_email(request, subject_template, template_html, to_mail, ctx_dict):
```

then I'm trying to call it from another python file that imports it.
I would like to use the autocomplete function of Pycharm in order to know which files I have available in my static files directory.

Though, when entering Ctrl+Space, it doesn't show any options.

The behavior DO work with functions such as render_to_response for some reason.
How could I activate it for custom functions and get the same behavior as in render_to_response.

Thanks[image]
[image]

Comment: which edition of pycharm?

Comment: Professional edition 4.0.3